# grails project about domain be update

Tags: grails, dom

```
class UserController {

  def userService;

  def execute() {

        try{
            User user=User.get(params.id.toLong());
            if(user){
              user.name="kevin";
              userService.updateUser(user);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            def map = ['exceptionmsg' : e.getMessage()];
            render map as JSON;
        }
   }

}
-------------------
class UserService {

    static transactional = true
    def updateUser(User user)throws Exception{
        user.desc="I'm a boy"
        throw new Exception("this test");
        if(!user.save()){
           throw new RuntimeException(user.error.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is not the real code, just like this format, the final result is throw exception and user be update.
You know why it?

Comment: a little formatting required as all the code are not formatted.

Comment: Maybe because `throws Exception` makes the exception a checked exception and the transaction only rolls back for unchecked exceptions. Try removing `throws Exception`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
class UserService {

    static transactional = true
    def updateUser(User user)throws Exception{
        user.desc="I'm a boy"
        //throw new Exception("this test"); 
        if(!user.save()){
           throw new RuntimeException(user.error.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

In 6 line you throw an Exception. Delete this line.